# OAuth with google service_account(server side) using httr

Tags: r, httr

I am developing a code using google apis for a server to server app.
I think I should use a service account oauth style.

But I could not solve the error below.

```
library(httr)

endpoint <- oauth_endpoints("google")
secrets <- jsonlite::fromJSON(file="~/dowloadFromGoogle.json")
scope <- "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
token <- oauth_service_token(endpoint, secrets, scope)
```

I get an error

```
Error in PKI::PKI.load.key(textConnection(private_key), private = TRUE) : 
cannot find RSA private key in PEM format
```

The json file I used is below. Probably I need to convert the jsonfile to a pem format? 
(I taken away some characters below.)

```
{
  "private_key_id": "6a82",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KwZ7u003d\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "aaa@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "aaa.apps.googleusercontent.com",
  "type": "service_account"
}
```

I tried below command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in aaa.p12 -nodes -nosecret > privatekey.pem
```

But, how do I load the pem format style in R?

On other language,
I am able to do a oauth with the python client library described in the url with a p12 file.
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount

Do I need use a p12 file for R code? If so, how do I write?